# How to insert an image in an existing docx file with Apache POI?

Tags: java, apache-poi, docx

**What is the problem?**
I am having troubles inserting an image into an existing docx file with Apache POI. When i open the docx file, i get an error message that the file is unreadable.

**When is the problem occuring?**
When i insert an image into a new instance of XWPFDocument with "new XWPFDocument()", everything works fine. When i create an instance of XWPFDocument with the input of an existing docx file, the error pops up.

**What am i trying to do?**
When the run text contains the text "[Signature]", i want to clear the text of the run and insert an image of a signature in that run.

**Which file am i using?**
Link: https://wetransfer.com/downloads/4cf6a680f290891a5fd53477d66c8abf20210616071837/41231b.

What am i doing wrong?

```
XWPFDocument doc = new XWPFDocument(new FileInputStream(inputURL));
doc = replaceFields(doc, replacings);

public static XWPFDocument replaceFields(XWPFDocument doc, HashMap<String, String> replacings) throws IOException, InvalidFormatException {
        int pCounter = 0;
        XWPFRun markedRun = null;
        for (XWPFParagraph p : doc.getParagraphs()) {
            pCounter++;
            List<XWPFRun> runs = p.getRuns();
            if (runs != null) {
                String text = "";
                int i = 1;
                for (XWPFRun run : runs) {
                    text = text + run.toString();
                    run.setText("", 0);
                    if (i == runs.size()) {
                        for (String key : replacings.keySet()) {
                            // Option 1: replacing value with trailing space
                            if (text.contains(key + " ") && replacings.get(key).equals("")) {
                                text = text.replace(key + " ", "");
                                continue;
                            }
                            // Option 2: Replacing value without trailing space
                            if (text.contains(key) && !replacings.get(key).equals("")) {
                                text = text.replace(key, replacings.get(key));
                                continue;
                            }
                            // Option 3: clearing empty values
                            if (text.contains(key) && replacings.get(key).equals("")) {
                                text = text.replace(key, "");
                                continue;
                            }
                        }
                        if (text.contains("[Signature]")) {
                            // Insert signature image
                            String signatureFile = "C:\\Users\\rick.van.baalen\\Downloads\\Prodin_Templates\\Signature_RVB.png";
                            InputStream is = new FileInputStream(signatureFile);
                            run.addPicture(is, XWPFDocument.PICTURE_TYPE_PNG, signatureFile, Units.toEMU(80), Units.toEMU(65));
                            is.close();
                        } else {
                            run.setText(text);
                        }
                    }
                    i++;
                }
                System.out.println("Line " + pCounter + ": " + text);
            }
        }
        
        return doc;
    }

doc.write(new FileOutputStream(outputURL));
```

Comment: The issue is not reproducible for me. Your approach - emptying all text runs in each paragraph and placing all text in last text run only - is not what I would do as this loses formatting. And `new XWPFDocument(OPCPackage.open(inputURL));` also is nothing I would do as closing `OPCPackage` will put changes in `inputURL` too. But nothing of that will lead to a corrupt document. Can you upload the file behind `inputURL` somewhere?

Comment: @AxelRichter i added the document to the question. Note: i'm not losing formatting/styling with this method. A bold line stays bold, even when i replaced text in the line.

Comment: The problem is the text box in first page header. If removed, it works. It is not clear to me where exactly is the problem. I can insert a text box in header using Insert > Text Box, and then select Simple Text Box from the pre-formatted text boxes and it works. If I do Insert > Text Box > Draw Text Box then after inserting a picture in the document, document gets corrupt. Weird.